# Solve the Following Non-Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

The equation to be solved is

$r^2 u''(r)-A(r^2\ u(r)u'(r)+2\ r\ u(r)^2)+2\ r\ u'(r)-2\ u(r)=0$

with boundary conditions $u(0)=u_0$ and $u(\infty)=0$.  Additionally it is assumed that $0<A<<1$.  A closed-form or "analytical" solution is sought--though it seems unlikely one can be found.  It is noted that under the transformation $y(r)=r^2\ u(r)$ the above equation transforms to,

$r^2\ y''(r)-(A\ y(r)+2\ r)y'(r)=0$

with boundary conditions appropriately modified.

This apparently simpler equation may be helpful in finding an closed-form *approximate* solution by treating the non-linear term perturbatively or via some other technique unknown to me.

Also, this problem may not be properly posed, in which case I am open to suggestions that would make it so.  It is apparently related to an engineering problem but, not being an engineer, I cannot say which one.

Your thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not convinced the transformation is helpful since $y(0)=0$ (so you can't recover $u(0)$) and then a solution for $y$ satisfying both BC's is $y=0$.

Comment: You're probably right.  I included it on he possibility that someone might recognize it.